# Default button in JFrame is not firing when the enter key is being pressed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, default

I have a `JFrame` with three JButtons on it. I have set `txtSearch` (a `JTextField` component) to have the focus when `JFrame` loads. One of the buttons is set as the default button. This is my code:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) 
{
     // btnRefresh.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R); // Even if this line 
                                               // is not commented, but
                                               // still the event wouldn't fire.
     this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnRefresh);
}
```

When it loads, the button is just selected, but it did nothing when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was being pressed. How do I correctly implement it?

```
btnRefresh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btnRefreshActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Pressed!");
    // Other codes here (Replace by JOptionPane)
}
```

Comment: I found that the easiest way is to call requestFocusInWindow() AFTER the JFrame is visible to set a default button. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What component has focus when the `JFrame` comes up?  I ask because some components "eat" the Enter key event.  For example, a `JEditorPane` will do that.

Also, when you assign an `ActionListener` to `JTextField`, the `ActionListener` will be called instead of the `DefaultButton` for the root pane.  You must choose either to have an `ActionListener` or a `DefaultButton`, but you can't have both fire for the same `JTextField`.  I'm sure this applies to other components as well.

Comment: I have set `JTextField` to be focused when `JFrame` loads.

Comment: correct analysis, not a solution :-) @johntotetwoo from your accepting this I assume it pointed it into the direction of a solution - you might consider to edit your question with that solution

Comment: Brilliant.. I have an actionListener on my password field and had failed to figure out that it was the cause of the defaultbutton not responding. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you are doing incorrectly from what is posted.  Here is a short example that works.  Perhaps it will reveal something useful to you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame 
{
  private JPanel    m_contentPane;
  private JTextField m_textField;

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ExampleFrame frame = new ExampleFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }

  /**
  * Create the frame.
   */
  public ExampleFrame()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    m_contentPane = new JPanel();
    m_contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    m_contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(m_contentPane);

    m_textField = new JTextField();
    m_contentPane.add(m_textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    m_textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Default");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ExampleFrame.this, "Default.");
        }
    });
    m_contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Not default");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ExampleFrame.this, "Not default.");
        }
    });
    m_contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    m_textField.requestFocus();
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnNewButton);
  }
}
```

Comment: add an actionListener to the textField and see what happens :-)

Comment: You nailed it kleopatra!  When I put in the ActionListener, the default button failed to fire.  johntotetwoo, you need to *remove* the action listener to have the default button fire.