# How to turn off a key listener in NetBeans wizard panels?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I developed a simple plugin for NetBeans IDE. I have a little problem with default key event on `TopComponenet` of Wizard panel:

#### For example:

I have a wizard with 3 steps. In second step I have a `JTextField` where user put some values and after that appear a `JList` below this text field. Everything is okay until user choose a some value from list and than press key <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then my panel goes to next Step 3. I attach a key listener to list something like:

```
list = new JList(new PackagesListModel());
list.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            JList list = (JList)evt.getSource();
            Object selectedPackage = list.getSelectedValue();
            typePackageField.setText((String)selectedPackage);
        }
    }
});
```

But this listener probably is invoking after default listener of `TopComponenet` on wizard. How can I prevent moving user to next step using ENTER key?

I don't want this action (when user press ENTER then they go to the next step).

**UPDATE:**

Forwarding to Kraal answer:

Problem is that i dont know where i can lookking for a JButton <kbd>Next</kbd> (to shuting down a listener). It sound strange but how i wrote. Im using a Netbeans Plaform WizzardDescriptor to generate a Wizzard (with 3 steps) . WizzardDescriptor is from package:

```
  org.openide.WizardDescriptor; // Dialogs API
```

i puted to him a 3 instances of panels: **WizardDescriptor.Panel** from same package:

```
  org.openide.WizardDescriptor // Dialogs API
```

it looks like:

```
    panels = new ArrayList<>();
    panels.add(new LayoutWizardPanel1(selectedLayout));
    panels.add(new LayoutWizardPanel2(selectedLayout));
    panels.add(new LayoutWizardPanel3(selectedLayout));
    WizardDescriptor wiz = new WizardDescriptor(new WizardDescriptor.ArrayIterator<>(panels));
```

After this will generated something like:

[image]

in my program i have access to WizardDescriptor

```
 http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-dialogs/org/openide/WizardDescriptor.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Everything is okay until user choose a some value from list and than press key ENTER then my panel goes to next Step 3. I attach a key
>   listener to list something like [...]*

If you want <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in your list has precedence over the default <kbd>Next -></kbd> button then you have to use [Key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to attach an action to your list when it's focused:

```
KeyStroke enterKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
Action updateTextfieldAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList)evt.getSource();
        Object selectedPackage = list.getSelectedValue();
        typePackageField.setText((String)selectedPackage );
    }
};

list = new JList(new PackagesListModel());
list.getInputMap().put(enterKeyStroke, "enter");
list.getActionMap().put("enter", updateTextfieldAction);
```

Note that [getInputMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap--) is a shortcut for [getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap-int-). This means that if your list has focus and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, then the action attached to this key stroke will be performed.

By this way your action will always have precedence over the next button's action, either if this button is the [default button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612020/default-button-in-jframe-is-not-firing-when-the-enter-key-is-being-pressed) or it has attached an action using key bindings using `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton(nextStepAction);
button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(enterKeyStroke, "enter");
button.getActionMap().put("enter", nextStepAction);
```

Where `nextStepAction` would be the action to go to wizard's next step.

See also [Key bindings vs. key listeners in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15290065/1795530)

---

### Example

Please cosider the example below. Note if you focus another component but list the the default action is performed. I've set the button as frame's root pane default button and I've attached an action using `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` just to prove that `WHEN_FOCUSED` action has precedence over those.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo {

    private JList list;
    private JTextField textField;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        KeyStroke enterKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);

        Action nextStepAction = new AbstractAction("Next") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Going to step 3!", "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        };

        Action updateTextfieldAction = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText((String)list.getSelectedValue());
            }
        };

        list = new JList(new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"});
        list.setPrototypeCellValue("This is a list's prototype cell value.");
        list.getInputMap().put(enterKeyStroke, "enter");
        list.getActionMap().put("enter", updateTextfieldAction);

        textField = new JTextField(15);

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        listPanel.add(textField);

        JButton button = new JButton(nextStepAction);
        button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(enterKeyStroke, "enter");
        button.getActionMap().put("enter", nextStepAction);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        buttonsPanel.add(button);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(listPanel);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Other comments

Please note that if you want avoid all this matter, you could attach a [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to your list and update the text field on selection change with no need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at all. In fact if you have access to the next step action you could enable/disable it based on list selection. By doing this you'll be sure that wizard can't continue if no item is selected in your list. IMHO that would be a more elegant way to handle this situation. See [Selecting Items in a List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but if you know which `JComponent` causes this behaviour, try this:

```
suspectedComponent.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER),"none");
```

To check which keystrokes are bound on a `JComponent`:

```
suspectedComponent.getInputMap().keys()
```

Or in the parent `InputMap`:

```
suspectedComponent.getInputMap().getParent().keys()
```

See the [docs for `InputMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) for details.

Comment: `"none"` should be used (to disable), rather than `null`, as seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto). Also keep in mind that there are three `InputMaps`. Just using `getInputMap()`, implicitly gets the `WHEN_FOCUSED`

Comment: Indeed, on the one hand, the document you're referring to states that "none" should be used. I saw it yesterday. However, on the other hand, the javadoc states that null should be used : "If actionMapKey is null, this removes the current binding for keyStroke". I would rather trust the javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html#put-javax.swing.KeyStroke-java.lang.Object-

Comment: hmm you're right. I'm too lazy to test it, but I remember befure, trying to use null didn't work for me. Maybe I'm mistaken. Thanks for the reference :-)

Comment: I knew I wasn't crazy. [There's a bug with null](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050223) :-)