# KeyListener on JComponent for Ctrl key

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, ctrl

I'd like to have a KeyListener on a JComponent in Swing that reacts on press and release of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. 
This a naive, but suboptimal solution (it reacts on every keypress, not only on press/release of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key:

```
new KeyAdapater() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.isControlDown()) {
       //do something
    }
  }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (!e.isControlDown()) {
       //do something other
    }
  }
}
```

What is a better approach to only trigger, when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key itself is pressed or released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh! I have used such an approach in the past, but just forgot. Thanks! That was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @radlan `What is a better approach to only trigger, when the ctrl key itself is pressed or released?` the question  asked what is the better approach. Well, the better approach is to use Key Bindings. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. `I have used such an approach in the past,` there is no need to use that approach in the future, now that you know the "better approach".

Answer (score 4):

IMHO using [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is a more flexible and reliable approach that brings with these benefits:

- Separates the action itself from the key strokes.
- There are different conditions to trigger those actions: [`WHEN_FOCUSED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [`WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_FOCUSED), [`WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
- We can take advantage of those conditions to attach different actions to different components relying on a precedence-based policy (see the example presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780177/1795530)).

Having said that, we can create `KeyStrokes` like follows:

```
KeyStroke controlKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, 0);
```

And we can even specify that the key stroke will be triggered on a key release event:

```
KeyStroke controlReleasedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, 0, true);
```

***Note:*** `0` means no modifiers and `true` is a flag indicating the key stroke represents a key release event. See [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-int-int-boolean-) for more details.

See also this topic: [Key bindings vs. key listeners in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java/15290065#15290065), and [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this too.